# Method to text analytics varchar(4000)

Tags: sql-server, azure, text-mining, text-analysis

In SQL Azure we have 20 million rows of English text stored in varchar(4000) describing why customers calling us for maintenance. Some examples are:

1. My windows is broken by a cat whose eyes are green.
2. The toilet is blocked and the kitchen is now full of bugs! This is worst nightmare i ever had!!!!
3. Please repair the bed.

The main purpose to be achieved is that we could identify most frequent words in the column, i.e. we know that Windows appears 1 million time in the database and bed repair 5 times only , therefore we could plan for stocks, hiring and training. Data are in Azure SQL. Could you recommend the best tool we should use in this scenario?

Comment: look at this :https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/machine-learning-apps-text-analytics/

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZ3v7MoufPAhXBRyYKHaFVCnUQFggnMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sqlsaturday.com%2FSessionDownload.aspx%3Fsuid%3D10720&usg=AFQjCNHxROcZnujFvaeHbu2mFFZwHI142Q&sig2=6QAY4ooKKPY4o-bUZOUJ9Q